# react-highcharts yAxis max/ceiling not working with many axis

Tags: highcharts, reactjs

I'm using react-highcharts, I have a graph with 2 yAxis one of these is a percentage and doesn't make sense to have values higher that 100%.

I'm trying to set 100 as a max value.
http://take.ms/lYjkT

(120% and 6 values are unnecessary)

I tried using 
- yAxis.max: 100 and yAxis.min: 0
- yAxis.ceiling: 100 and yAxis.floor: 0
- yAxis.maxPadding: 0, yAxis.minPadding: 0

also I tried using yAxis.tickInterval, yAxis.minRange, yAxis.endOnTick but nothing works.
Other thing I tried is to use 
- chart.alignTicks: false
and it looks better
http://take.ms/2PLiL

But 0 should be at bottom of the graph, also I prefer to use alingTicks:true and cut the unnecessary values.

This is the config I'm using

```
yAxis: [{
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      title: {
      text: '',
      style: {
        color: window.Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
     },
     labels: {
       format: '{value}',
       style: {
         color: window.Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
       }
     },
   },
     { 
       gridLineWidth: 0,
       maxPadding: 0,
       minPadding: 0,
       minRange: 100,
       ceiling:100,
       floor: 0,
       title: {
         text: '',
         style: {
           color: window.Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
         }
       },
       labels: {
         format: '{value}%',
         style: {
           color: window.Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
         }
       },
       opposite: true
     }]
```

Do you know how to do it work?

Comment: Setting to false startOnTick and endOnTick for yAxis should resolve your problem, but I am not able to recreate your chart - http://jsfiddle.net/m3qn51kc/ Could you post a working demo if setting those two options will not help?

Comment: I used it on a complete example, on this https://jsfiddle.net/1xrua4sn/ but it's working ok. I guess it's an issue from the react-highcharts plugin.

Comment: Are you using Highcharts official way? More info here: http://www.highcharts.com/blog/192-use-highcharts-to-create-charts-in-react